# Perform a numerical constrained integration over $[-1,1]^3$

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like an estimate of the three-dimensional volume lying within the 
cube $[-1,1]^3$ of the body defined by the constraints (the three variables being $t1, t2, t3$)

```
-(1/2) < t3 < 1/2 && -(1/2) < t2 < 1/2 && 4 t1^2 < (1 - 2 t3)^2 && 4 t1^2 < (1 + 2 t3)^2 && (Abs[t1] + Abs[t2] + Abs[t3])^2 > 1/2 && 6912 t1^2 t2^2 t3^2 <= 1
```

I've tried several of the NIntegrate Methods, using the Boole command. Method->"MonteCarlo" seems to be the most "realistic", but only accurate to one or two places, varying MaxPoints. Several of the Methods signal that  "The number of piecewise regions has exceeded the maximum value 
specified by the option MaxPiecewiseCases -> 100".

Answer (score 6):

Your constraint:

```
constraint = -(1/2) < t3 < 1/2 && -(1/2) < t2 < 1/2 && 4 t1^2 < (1 - 2 t3)^2 && 4 t1^2 < (1 + 2 t3)^2 && (Abs[t1] + Abs[t2] + Abs[t3])^2 > 1/2 && 6912 t1^2 t2^2 t3^2 <= 1;
```

Here's a couple more approaches to obtain the volume using [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion):

```
NIntegrate[1, t ∈ ImplicitRegion[constraint, {t1,t2,t3}]]
```

> 0.0758044

and:

```
Volume[ImplicitRegion[constraint,{t1,t2,t3}], WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision]
```

> 0.0758044

[`Volume`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Volume) will try to produce an exact answer, so I enforce a numerical approximation with the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision) option.

Comment: I tried the indicated Volume command without the WorkingPrecision option, and it gave a numerical result--0.0758044. Maybe it gave up on an exact solution, and reverted to the numerical one?

Answer (score 3):

First look on the "body"

```
RegionPlot3D[-(1/2) < t3 < 1/2 && -(1/2) < t2 < 1/2 && 4 t1^2 < (1 - 2 t3)^2 &&4 t1^2 < (1 + 2 t3)^2 && (Abs[t1] + Abs[t2] + Abs[t3])^2 > 1/2 &&6912 t1^2 t2^2 t3^2 <= 1
, {t1, -1, 1}, {t2, -1, 1}, {t3, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100,MaxRecursion -> 4, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

shows two parts.

In the next step I define a region for one part (t2>0)

```
cube = ImplicitRegion[-(1/2) < t3 < 1/2 && 0 < t2 < 1/2 &&4 t1^2 < (1 - 2 t3)^2 &&4 t1^2 < (1 + 2 t3)^2 && (Abs[t1] + Abs[t2] + Abs[t3])^2 > 1/2 && 6912 t1^2 t2^2 t3^2 <= 1
, {{t1, -1, 1}, {t2, -1, 1}, {t3, -1, 1}}]
```

The volume of this part evaluates to

```
Volume[ DiscretizeRegion[cube, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001] ]
(*0.0346886*)
```

For this single part although `NIntegrate`together with `Boole` evaluates without error to

```
NIntegrate[Boole[ 4 t1^2 < (1 - 2 t3)^2 && 4 t1^2 < (1 + 2 t3)^2 && (RealAbs[t1] + RealAbs[t2] + RealAbs[t3])^2 > 1/2 && 6912 t1^2 t2^2 t3^2 <= 1], 
{t1, -1,1}, {t2, 0, 1/2}, {t3, -1/2, 1/2}]
(*0.0379022*)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the that the resolution of your implicit region is too small. This problem be reduced with the `MaxCellMeasure` option in `DiscretizedRegion`. Reducing it, leads to a converging result:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[
     -(1/2) < t3 < 1/2 &&
      -(1/2) < t2 < 1/2
      && 4 t1^2 < (1 - 2 t3)^2
      && 4 t1^2 < (1 + 2 t3)^2
      && (Abs[t1] + Abs[t2] + Abs[t3])^2 > 1/2
      && 6912 t1^2 t2^2 t3^2 <= 1
     , {t1, t2, t3}];

data = Table[   
   d1 = DiscretizeRegion[ir, MaxCellMeasure -> mcellm];
   {mcellm, d1, NIntegrate[1, {t1, t2, t3} \[Element] d1]}
   , {mcellm, Table[10.0^(-i), {i, 3, 7}]}];

plot = Grid[{data[[All, 1]],data[[All, 3]],data[[All, 2]]}];
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "implicit_region_integration_resolution_plot.png"}], 
  plot];
```